# ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword, SQL statement was not passed to the DBMS, SAS will do the processing

Tags: sql, oracle, sas, sas-macro

I am so frustrated with this piece of code.  I'm trying to pass in values using syspbuff which I do all the time.  However, I want to pass in multiple values but for this UNION code I'm trying to do, it's giving me trouble.  I am going from Oracle to SAS which I assume is causing the problem but I'd like an answer as to why.  Previously, I had the source tables in temp space (SAS) and I didn't get this error.  But when I had to create the tables in MYDB (Oracle) because of a specific reason, I started getting the large log with "failure to pass through" errors.

Interestingly, the code actually works and it does what I want it to but the problem is that I get a pop up that the log is too large and will open externally. Then it opens a text file that is HUGE and has tons of errors basically saying that it couldn't pass through the code into implicit pass through.  I wasn't trying to do pass through for this particular piece of code.  So, again, it works and I ultimately get what I want but the log issue is driving me bonkers.

```
%macro ALLPROVTYPE() / parmbuff; 
    %do ii = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&syspbuff.))); 
    %let FT=%scan(%bquote(&SYSPBUFF),&ii);  

CREATE TABLE MYSASLIB.ALLST_PROV_&FT._NULL AS
SELECT "AK" AS STATE,*
FROM MYDB.AK_PROV_&FT 

%macro JNSTS() / parmbuff; 
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&syspbuff.))); 
    %let ST=%scan(%bquote(&SYSPBUFF),&i); 

UNION CORR

SELECT "&ST" AS STATE,*
FROM MYDB.&ST._PROV_&FT

      %end;
%mend JNSTS;
%JNSTS(&&PROVALL&FT);
;
      %end;
%mend ALLPROVTYPE;

PROC SQL;
%ALLPROVTYPE(&PROVNUMS);
QUIT;
```

ACCESS ENGINE: ERROR: ORACLE prepare error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword. SQL statement: DEBUG: DBMS engine returned an error - NO Implicit Passthru.
DEBUG: Error during prepare of:

Comment: Debug the code you are generating before generating it with a macro.  You can use the MPRINT option to see what code lines your macro is generating. Copy those and debug them to remove the errors and then re-work the macro to generate the error free code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understood this query is, you are creating multiple tables, and each table is created as a select statement which is constructed through multiple select statements that are joined via a UNION CORR. Essentially something like:

```
create table <something> as
  (select <something> as state, * from <something> union corr 
   select <something> as state, * from <something> union corr
   select <something> as state, * from <something>);
```

Is this correct?

If yes, your macro code had some syntactically problematic nesting going on. Try the following code (though I wasn't able to fully verify it since I don't have information about the inputs to the macros):

```
/* Since this needs to be passed between the two macros */
%global FT;

%macro ALLPROVTYPE() / parmbuff;
    %do ii = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&syspbuff.)));
        %let FT=%scan(%bquote(&SYSPBUFF),&ii);
        CREATE TABLE MYSASLIB.ALLST_PROV_&FT._NULL AS (
            %JNSTS(&&PROVALL&FT)
            );
    %end;
%mend;

%macro JNSTS() / parmbuff;
    %do jj = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&syspbuff.)));
        %let ST=%scan(%bquote(&SYSPBUFF),&jj);
        SELECT "&ST" AS STATE,* FROM MYDB.&ST._PROV_&FT

        %if &jj NE %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&syspbuff.))) %then
        %do;
            UNION CORR
        %end;
    %end;
%mend;

PROC SQL;
    %ALLPROVTYPE(&PROVNUMS);
QUIT;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This doesn't resolve the pass-through log issue but I'm very happy to receive a more syntactically correct version of my macro and I love that I don't have to break out the Table 1 before the union tables as I had it before.  This actually made things a lot easier for me in several other programs I have.  I don't entirely understand how this line selects the table one and knows to join the remaining tables.  Can you explain?
    %if &jj NE %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&syspbuff.))) %then %do

Comment: ```%if &jj NE %sysfunc(countw(%bquote(&syspbuff.))) ``` basically is "ff jj is not equal to the maximum value to loop through" -  this just simply avoids putting a `UNION CORR` on the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: It will help if you give some example of how your inputs to the macro look like and what your output sql should look like. I cooked up this solution based on the assumption I have stated above on how the SQL statement would look like which may be quite incorrect.

Comment: Also, I think since you are doing pass-thru mode, you cannot use UNION CORR which won't be recognized by ORACLE

Comment: Bingo!  That must be it.  Since I was trying to convert an Oracle schema table to a SAS server, it must have been automatically trying to pass the code through using implicit pass through.  I didn't realize that UNION was SAS specific.  So the implicit pass through was failing.  It makes sense now!  Thank you.  And thanks for explaining the %if NE %then %do.  As I mentioned, I updated several of my programs with this improved syntax and it has proved VERY helpful!  So thanks again and have a great day!  BTW, your assumption on what the SQL would look like was exactly right.

Comment: To be clear, UNION is not SAS specific. UNION CORRESPONDING is. Glad you got it figured out.